# Camera showing a low framerate on line-tracking car using Raspberry 4 and Raspberry Pi Camera V1

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi4

We are working on a line-tracking car using openCV and MQTT and we went into a problem with the camera having very low fps (approximately 3-4fps), which caused our car not to be able to process the data slowly resulting in the car will get derailed from the line every run.
This is my full code.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import picamera
import time
import paho.mqtt.publish as publish
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
broker_address = "35.165.89.144"
topic = "linetracking"
topic2 = "Carcontrol"
port = 1883
activated = False
signal = None

# Set up GPIO mode
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
# Set min distance to stop
min_distance = 3

# Set GPIO pin of L298N to Raspberry 4
in1 = 13
in2 = 12
in3 = 21
in4 = 20
en1 = 6
en2 = 26


# Set GPIO pin of HC-SR04 to Raspberry 4
trig = 23
echo = 24

# Initialize GPIO Pin as outputs
GPIO.setup(trig, GPIO.OUT)
# Initialize GPIO Pin as input
GPIO.setup(echo, GPIO.IN)

# Set speed for car
initialvaluespeed = 40
speed_turn = 60
speed = 35

# Initialize GPIO Pin as outputs
GPIO.setup(en1, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(en2, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(in1, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(in2, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(in3, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(in4, GPIO.OUT)

# Initialize power of L289N motor
p1 = GPIO.PWM(en1, 100)
p2 = GPIO.PWM(en2, 100)

# Clear the  start speed of car
p1.start(initialvaluespeed)
p2.start(initialvaluespeed)

# Clear  pins of L298N motor
GPIO.output(in1, GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.output(in2, GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.output(in3, GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.output(in4, GPIO.LOW)

# Change speed function


def pause():
    GPIO.output(in1, GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.output(in2, GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.output(in3, GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.output(in4, GPIO.LOW)


def changeSpeed():
    p1.start(speed)
    p2.start(speed)

# Change speed turn function


def changeSpeedTurn():
    p1.start(speed_turn)
    p2.start(speed_turn)

# Change default speed  function


def setSpeedDefault():
    p1.start(initialvaluespeed)
    p2.start(initialvaluespeed)

# Stop function


def stop():
    message = "Stop"
    print("Stop")
    GPIO.output(in1, GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.output(in2, GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.output(in3, GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.output(in4, GPIO.LOW)
    publish.single(topic, message, hostname=broker_address)


# Turn right function


def turn_right():
    message = "Turn Right"
    print("Turn Right")
    changeSpeedTurn()
    GPIO.output(in1, GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.output(in2, GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.output(in3, GPIO.HIGH)
    GPIO.output(in4, GPIO.LOW)
    time.sleep(2)
    publish.single(topic, message, hostname=broker_address)

# Go forward function, stop when see obstackle


def forward():
    distance(min_distance)
    message = "On Track"
    print("Forward")
    changeSpeed()
    GPIO.output(in1, GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.output(in2, GPIO.HIGH)
    GPIO.output(in3, GPIO.HIGH)
    GPIO.output(in4, GPIO.LOW)
    time.sleep(2)

    publish.single(topic, message, hostname=broker_address)

# Turn left function


def turn_left():
    message = "Turn Left"
    print("Turen Left")
    changeSpeedTurn()
    GPIO.output(in1, GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.output(in2, GPIO.HIGH)
    GPIO.output(in3, GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.output(in4, GPIO.LOW)
    time.sleep(2)
    publish.single(topic, message, hostname=broker_address)


# Go backward function


def backward():
    message = "Go Backwards"
    print("Backward")
    changeSpeed()
    GPIO.output(in1, GPIO.HIGH)
    GPIO.output(in2, GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.output(in3, GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.output(in4, GPIO.HIGH)
    publish.single(topic, message, hostname=broker_address)


# Check obstacle


def distance(min_distance):
    while True:
        # Send a trigger pulse to the HC-SR04
        GPIO.output(trig, GPIO.LOW)
        time.sleep(0.2)
        GPIO.output(trig, GPIO.HIGH)
        time.sleep(0.00001)
        GPIO.output(trig, GPIO.LOW)

        # Measure the duration of the echo pulse
        while GPIO.input(echo) == GPIO.LOW:
            pulse_start = time.time()

        while GPIO.input(echo) == GPIO.HIGH:
            pulse_end = time.time()
        pulse_duration = pulse_end - pulse_start
        # Calculate the distance to the object
        distance = pulse_duration * 17150
        if distance > min_distance:
            return True
        else:
            stop()


def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print("Connected with result code " + str(rc))
    client.subscribe(topic2)


def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    print(" " + str(msg.payload))
    signal = str(msg.payload)
    global activated
    if signal == "b'ACTIVATE'":
        activated = True
    elif signal == "b'DEACTIVATE'":
        activated = False


def process_image():
    with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
        # Set capture resolution
        camera.resolution = (640, 480)
        camera.framerate = 60
        while activated:
            frame = np.empty((480, 640, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
            # Capture video
            camera.capture(frame, 'bgr', use_video_port=True)
            # Flip capture
            crop_frame = cv2.flip(frame, 0)

            # Crop frame in the capture
            size = 300
            x = (640 - size)//2
            y = (480 - 300) // 2
            crop_size = 300
            crop_frame = crop_frame[y:y+300, x:x+crop_size]

            # Increase brightness
            # gamma = 1.5
            # crop_frame = cv2.pow(crop_frame / 255.0, gamma)
            # crop_frame = cv2.normalize(
            # crop_frame, None, 0, 255, cv2.NORM_MINMAX, cv2.CV_8UC1)

            # Convert to GrayScale
            gray = cv2.cvtColor(crop_frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

            # Apply GaussianBlur to the grayscale iamge
            blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 0)

            ret, thresh1 = cv2.threshold(
                blur, 25, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)  # Thresh hold the image

            mask = cv2.erode(thresh1, None, iterations=2)
            mask = cv2.dilate(mask, None, iterations=2)

            _, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(
                mask.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

            if len(contours) > 0:
                c = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)
                if len(c) > 0:
                    M = cv2.moments(c)
                    cx = int(M['m10'] / M['m00'])
                    cy = int(M['m01'] / M['m00'])
                    cv2.line(crop_frame, (cx, 0), (cx, 720),
                                (255, 0, 0), 1)  # draw cx
                    cv2.line(crop_frame, (0, cy),
                                (1280, cy), (255, 0, 0), 1)  # draw cy
                    cv2.drawContours(crop_frame,
                                        contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), 1)  # draw contours

                    # print cordidate cx and cy
                    print(cx, cy, end='')
                    print()
                    time.sleep(1)
                    # Control the car base on cordidate cx
                    if cx >= 230:
                        turn_right()
                        time.sleep(0.5)
                        pause()

                    elif cx < 325 and cx > 75:
                        forward()
                        time.sleep(0.5)
                        pause()
                    elif cx <= 75:
                        turn_left()
                        time.sleep(0.5)
                        pause()
                else:
                    backward()
                # Show the capture with contour
                cv2.imshow('Track Line', crop_frame)
                if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                    camera.stop_preview()
                    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
                    p1.stop()
                    p2.stop()
                    GPIO.cleanup()
                    break


client = mqtt.Client()
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.connect(broker_address, port, 60)
client.on_message = on_message


# Initialize Rasp Pi camera
while True:
    client.loop_start()
    if activated:
        process_image()
    else:
        pause()
    client.loop_stop()
```

I think it is mainly because the Rasberry Pi camera v1 is too slow compared to the other versions but I don't think that's the main reason. It will be a lot of help if you can pinpoint where I went wrong in my codes and tell me how to fix it.
Thank you very much

Comment: Did you try to add some timestamp logging and examine which part of your code consumes most of the time? There are some `sleep(0.5)` operations in your code. Did you try to decouple image processing and car control using non-blocking techniques, e.g. multi-threading? Please add more details like debugging/profiling information to your question! [ask]